# Filter out (py3) UnicodeEncodeError-generating characters with Vim

Tags: python, vim

This has bothered me for a while. I have large amounts of data exported from other programs or Internet sources. I try to separate these data into strings or rstrings and then filter the strings.

I cannot copy any "illegal characters" into this field, so I can't put any example code. I also cannot copy these characters into the Python3 interpreter (they're switched to '?').

I can copy/import them into Vim, though they appear as black squares. Copying the imported data into Notebook and saving as *.txt eliminates most of the problems, but not all. I don't care--much--about saving the characters. Deleting them would be fine, although simply ignoring them would be even better.

Comment: How is this text encoded?  UTF-8, Latin-1, UTF-16, something else?

Comment: I'm guessing UTF-8. I'm not sure. The data usually come from Microsoft Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your data is in UTF-8.  If this is wrong, we'll probably lose a lot of valid Unicode characters, so you may need to change this assumption.  In particular, if every other character looks invalid, try UTF-16 (both LE and BE).

```
with open('path/to/file.txt', mode='rt', encoding='utf_8', errors='ignore') as file:
    contents = file.read()
```

That will pull the entire contents of the file into a string, ignoring anything that's not valid UTF-8.  You can then do with the string as you please.

If the file is very large, you may want to open a new file for writing and pass both files to [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj); that will push the data into the new file without consuming massive amounts of memory.

Comment: @Shay: When you're opening the file for writing, make sure you specify the encoding explicitly rather than letting Python guess.  Pass `encoding='utf_8'` to your second `open()` call.